# Why does this bash script create a new directory?

Tags: bash, boolean-logic, mkdir

I am new to using bash scripts (I have only been learning it for the past few hours as a part of a larger project), and I am trying to understand this piece of code in bash script:

```
for newDir in `cat tempfile.list` ; do
        dir=/Tree/Apples/$newDir
        [ -d $dir ] || mkdir -p $dir/{log,err}
done
```

What does [-d $dir] do? And does this code create a new directory named `dirName` within the `Apples` directory? If so, why does it do that? I don't see a statement that says `mkdir dirName`. Can someone please explain in general what the statement `[ -d $dir ] || mkdir -p $dir/{log,err}`does? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: See: `help test | grep -- -d`

Comment: @Cyrus Is there a link to a question related to what you want me to look at?

Comment: This might help: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%5B+-d+%24dir+%5D+%7C%7C+mkdir+-p+%24dir%2F%7Blog%2Cerr%7D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
command1 || command2
```

is a short way of writing

```
if ! command1
then
    command2
fi
```

`||` is a logical test with short-circuiting, similar to most programming languages; if the left-hand operand succeeds, it doesn't execute the right-hand operand.

`[ -d $dir ]` tests whether a directory named `$dir` already exists. So if this test fails, it executes `mkdir -p $dir/{log,err}`.

`mkdir` creates directories, and when it's given the `-p` option it will create any intermediate directories that are needed to create the target directory.

Braces around a comma-separated list are used to automatically repeat part of a command, so `$dir/{log,err}` is a shortcut for `$dir/log $dir/err`. So the full mkdir command expands to

```
mkdir -p $dir/log $dir/err
```

So what this script does is create all the directories listed in `tempfile.list` that don't already exist, and create `log` and `err` subdirectories within the ones that it created.